# Edit RefCell in closure

Tags: rust, closures, smart-pointers

I want to store a closure in struct that implements Clone, so i'm code this:

```
use std::rc::Rc;

type Closure = Box<dyn Fn() -> ()>;

#[derive(Clone)]
struct A {
    closure: Option<Rc<Closure>>,
}

impl A {
    pub fn new() -> A {
        A { closure: None }
    }

    pub fn closure(&self) -> Option<Rc<Closure>> {
        self.closure.clone()
    }

    pub fn set_closure(&mut self, closure: Closure) -> &mut Self {
        self.closure = Some(Rc::new(closure));
        self
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut a: A = A::new();

    a.set_closure(Box::new(|| -> () { println!("Works fine!") }));
    (a.closure().unwrap())();
}
```

Now I want to test this code by borrowing a variable of current scope. It's important to keep a reference in main function, because i need to use it after.
I code this:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;

fn main() {
    let mut a: A = A::new();
    let value: Rc<RefCell<i8>> = Rc::new(RefCell::new(0));

    println!("Value = {}", value.borrow());

    a.set_closure(Box::new(|| -> () {
        *value.borrow_mut() = 1;
    }));
    (a.closure().unwrap())();

    println!("New value = {}", value.borrow());
}
```

But I get this error:

```
Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0597]: `value` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:34:38
   |
34 |   a.set_closure(Box::new(|| -> () { *value.borrow_mut() = 1; }));
   |                 ---------------------^^^^^---------------------
   |                 |        |           |
   |                 |        |           borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                 |        value captured here
   |                 cast requires that `value` is borrowed for `'static`
...
38 | }
   | - `value` dropped here while still borrowed
```

Would anyone know what I need to do please.
Thank you for your reply in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Rc`s are shared by cloning, which increments their reference count. But you pass a reference to it to the closure, which is perhaps defeating the point of using an `Rc` in the first place. As the error says, the closure is holding a reference to `value` after `value` is dropped.

You probably intended to write something like this, which clones the `Rc` and moves the clone into the closure:

```
let cloned_value = value.clone();
a.set_closure(Box::new(move || *cloned_value.borrow_mut() = 1));
```

Or (my preference) avoiding introducing a new binding in the outer scope:

```
a.set_closure(Box::new({
    let value = value.clone();
    move || *value.borrow_mut() = 1
}));
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I didn't think of trying to clone the `Rc`. I tested it and it works.
I also tested your second suggestion but it doesn't work. Do you know why?
[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=91ff8cde1a8c6d70130fe5cd0d9ae8bc). So much for me, I read with squinting eyes of the morning. It works :D thanks you  
[Playground OK](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cca25445287197a070df9d41fa9e3f65)